# NuGet error NU1301 when trying to dotnet restore

Tags: .net, nuget

When trying to do a "dotnet restore" (inside a docker build command), I get the following error:

```
 > [build 4/5] RUN dotnet restore:
0.994   Determining projects to restore...
8.298 /app/MudBlazorCICDTest.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/app/MudBlazorCICDTest.sln]
14.06 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.101/NuGet.targets(156,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/app/MudBlazorCICDTest.sln]
14.06 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.101/NuGet.targets(156,5): error :   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [/app/MudBlazorCICDTest.sln]
14.06 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.101/NuGet.targets(156,5): error :   The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain [/app/MudBlazorCICDTest.sln]
```

If I copy and paste the given URL (https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json) into a browser, in this case Chrome, it works.
So in theory I should be able to reach the site.

I try to publish a MudBlazor-Project as a docker image. The Dockerfile has the following content:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./

RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM nginx:1.25.3
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /app/out/wwwroot /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our firewall admin had to change the settings.
The adress was blocked by the firewall.